# Tcl access contents of a loop item item

Tags: loops, tcl

I've created variables based off a array and then populated that variable with the results of that array and trying to access that variable in a loop to replace text within a string.

I have an array

```
mookie profile:alias:0 mookie
mookie profile:class:0 hacker
mookie profile:inventory:0 DigitalHackerDevice
mookie profile:inventory:1 BootDisk
mookie profile:inventory:2 HackThePlanet99
```

and I get all of the array and store it

```
#get_userSprite is defined via an HTML form so "mookie" for this example
set array "[lsort -dictionary [array names $get_userSprite]]"
```

I have a loop which populates $ with the key (alias, class, inventory)

```
foreach item $array {

set datastoreKey [lindex [string map {":" " "} $item] 1] ;#alias, class, inventory

#using the array string profile:alias:0 get the item
set array_string [getItem $get_userSprite $item] ;#get the result for profile:alias:0 returns "mookie"

lappend $datastoreKey "$array_string" ;# this then creates variables with the result of that.

#$alias eq mookie
#$class eq hacker
#$inventory eq item1,item2,item3
} ;#close loop
```

I can confirm these are populated

```
puts $class ;# returns mookie
puts $alias ;# returns merchant
puts $inventory ;# returns DigitalHackerDevice, item1, item2
```

I've also stored a list of the three fields I wish to access

```
if { $datastoreKey ni $myList } { lappend myList [list $datastoreKey] } else { puts "Don't append" }
```

so myList now contains: alias class inventory

I have a tagswap procedure which replaces "word with string" in a variable

```
proc tagSwap {craft values} { return [string map $values $craft] } ;#Preforms morph of words.
```

so

```
foreach item $myList {

puts $item ;#alias class inventory
set swaps [tagSwap $string [list "$item" "$item"]] 
} ;#end loop
```

I'm dumbstruck on how to how to access the contents of $alias to replace the word "alias" with "mookie" in the string because $item is "alias" and it replaces it with that and so on for the rest. Class, Inventory etc..

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results do not match the input data you provided. Ignoring that, your question seems to boil down to: I have a variable "item", containing the name of another variable. How do I dump the value of that other variable?

While this can be done using `puts [set $item]`, it is usually easier to change your code to use array members instead of scalar variables.

So instead of `lappend $datastoreKey "$array_string"`, use `lappend datastore($datastoreKey) "$array_string"`. Then getting the value of the item is just a matter of: `puts $datastore($item)`

This also avoids the risk of any item name clashing with variables you use in your code.

Comment: This looks to get to the core of the question. Also, anything truly complicated is probably better put in SQL; SQLite is _excellent_ for Tcl and an in-memory database is a good replacement for an array when more complex querying is wanted. This sounds like an application where that'll be true…

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be down to something simple such as this. The thought just didn't pass my mind. @DonalFellows I'll bare that in mind, but I was looking to avoid anything SQL.